# Using ffmpeg to stream live video from a raspberry pi to a web server for distribution

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming

I am trying to build a device that will encode h.264 video on a raspberrypi and stream it out to a separate web server in the cloud. The main issue I am having is most implementations I search for either have the web server directly on the pi or have the embedded player playing video directly from the device.

I would like it to be pretty much plug and play no matter what network I am on ie no port forwarding of any sort all I need to do is connect the device to the network and the stream will be visible on a webpage.

One possible solution to the issue is just simply encode frames in base 64 as jpegs and send them to a an endpoint on the webserver, however, this is a huge waste of bandwidth and wont allow for the framerate h.264 would.

Any idea on some possible technologies that could be used to do this?

I feel like it can be done with some websockets or zmq and ffmpeg somehow but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could provide more description of the architecture of the device.  Since it is an RPI, it is probably also being used for video acquisition via the camera expansion port.  If this is the case, you can access the video device and do quite a bit with respect to streaming using the combination of available command line tools.

Something like the following will produce an RTMP stream from the video camera host.

```
raspivid [preferred options] -o - | ffmpeg -i - [preferred options] rtmp://[IP ADDR]/[location]
```

From there, `FFmpeg` will do a lot of heavy lifting for you.

This will now enable remote hosts to access the RTMP stream.

Other tools that would complement that architecture may be `ffserver` where the rtmp stream from the rpi host could be acquired and then be made available to a variety of clients such as a player in a webpage.  Quick look shows `ffserver` may be obsolete, but that there are analogous components.

Comment: Sorry I will be using a USB webcam. I have found much of this code to send out the RTMP stream in other examples. The part that is not covered is how to receive the stream and streamer it on the server side.

Comment: Please update your question to include architectural  needs on the RTMP receiver side. Look at Wowza's services to get a feel for how this is done commercially.